# 2 way SSL between nginx and backend server

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I have a backend server on Node.js and I am trying to setup 2 way SSL between Nginx and this backend server.

But I get an error as: 
`2015/11/02 06:51:02 [error] 12840#12840: *266 upstream SSL certificate does not match "myLocalMachine" while SSL handshaking to upstream,`

and this is when I set `proxy_ssl_verify on`. If its `off` then it works fine. Following is my Nginx setup:

```
upstream myLocalMachine {
    server MyPublicIP:8888;
}

server {
    listen 8222 ssl;
    proxy_cache two;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/client-cert.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    location / {
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_ssl_verify on;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/backend-server-cert.pem;
            proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;
            proxy_ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/ssl/pwd.pass;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass https://myLocalMachine;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_cache_valid any   1m;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
            #proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
            proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
            proxy_cache_key "$request_body";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the server side code for better understanding.

Comment: Does your backend server certificate covers (Common Name or Subject AlternativeName DNS) the "myLocalMachine" host ? You cannot connect to a host whose DNS alias is DNS_ALIAS if DNS_ALIAS is not the Common Name field or included in the SubjectAlternativeName list.

Comment: I am using openssl to generate certificates but I don't know how to set value of SubjectAlternativeName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I had used url in certificates lets say: `example.com` but I was using some
custom name as `myLocalMachine` in upstream and proxy_pass which I replaced it with url.

Use url in upstream block & proxy_pass as below

```
upstream example.com {
    # ip & ports are for examples
    server 11.11.11.11:2222;
}

proxy_pass https://example.com;
```

Comment: according to http://adolgarev.blogspot.com/2013/12/nginx-two-way-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: why current certificates names ends with `.pem`? and what is `ssl/pwd.pass` ?

Comment: why current certificates names ends with .pem?
Ans: .pem is one of the format used by Node.js for SSL certificates

what is ssl/pwd.pass?
ssl is the name of folder and pwd.pass is the file which contains the password used by private key.